# Azure: execute a container instance with parameters

Tags: azure, azure-container-instances

I have a container in a Azure Container Registry. I have made a container instance from the registry. This container runs a script.sh at the entry point and echo's a value.

```
FROM ubuntu
WORKDIR /docker
COPY . .
ENTRYPOINT ["./script.sh"]
```

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -z $1 ]] ; then
   echo "simple task: no parameters were passed"
else
   echo $1
fi
```

How do I execute the container and give it a different starting value ?

In docker we can just put values at the end of docker run. The container runs using the referenced image, executes the script and deletes the running container.

```
docker run --rm --name "simple-temp" "simple" "value1" "value1"
```

I want the equivalent of this command. Create and run an instance using the registry, run the entry point once, shutdown and delete container. How do I accomplish this in Azure Container Instances ? If not Container Instances, which service to use ?

Comment: It looks like they only support environment variables for example `az container create -g MyResourceGroup --name myapp --image myimage:latest --environment-variables key1=value1 key2=value2` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/containerapp?view=azure-cli-latest or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/container?view=azure-cli-latest depending which one you use )

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Docker ACI even for Azure ACI.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/quickstart-docker-cli